# slim gem and Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 5.1
```

When I generated the initial application, Rails created some default layouts:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
```

I would like to use the slim-rails gem. The documentation says all I need to do is include it in the Gemfile, and any views I generate, will be .slim views.

What about the views in the app/views/layouts folder? How do I convert those to .slim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it manually. `application.html.erb` is just a few lines of code.

Replace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

With

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title MyApp
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  body
    = yield
```

And rename the file.

Same for other files.

**If you have more work to do you could use:**

- [Online Converter](http://erb2slim.com/)
- [html2slim gem](https://github.com/slim-template/html2slim)